# Динамический related_name для модели

Tags: python-3.x, django, model

Как создать динамический related_name для классов, унаследованных от абстрактного класса

Пример:

```
class AbstractTagChat(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    tag = ''

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.chat = models.OneToOneField('Chat', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='%s_chat' % cls.tag)
        super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)

    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class TelegramChat(AbstractTagChat):
    tag = 'telegram'


class VkChat(AbstractTagChat):
    tag = 'vk'
```

Соответсвенно к объектам VkChat и TelegramChat нужно получать доступ из Chat через chat.vk_chat и chat.telegram_chat соответсвенно.

Пробовал указывать поле непосредственно в классе, но это не сработало (ошибки E300, E307, говорится, что унаследован от абстратного класса и что то еще, короче тот подход уже был неверным)

Comment: В документации есть про это https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name, попробуйте `related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related"`. Для вашего случая будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В django предусмотрены специальные ключевые слова для для назначения динамического related_name **дочерним моделям абстрактного класса** - т.е только тем моделям, которые являются непосредственными потомками абстрактного класса: app_label и class

В вашем случае возможно их использование:

```
class AbstractTagChat(models.Model): 
    class Meta: 
        abstract = True 

    chat = models.OneToOneField('Chat', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='%(class)s_chat')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Соответственно, на выходе будет `telegram_chat` и `vk_chat`

Comment: Кстати, не сработала ссылка на модель через указание строкой и ругался на подчеркивания. остальное сработало :)